# NSUserUnixTask ignores script quietly

Tags: swift, macos, shell, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm writing a sandboxed app in Swift 4 on macOS High Sierra using Xcode 9. My app has a shell script file (say, `myscript`) copied to the `Bundle.main.resourceURL` directory when installing. I want to run this shell script using `NSUserUnixTask` as follows:

```
if let scriptUrl = URL(string: "myscript", relativeTo: Bundle.main.resourceURL) {
    do {
        let task = try NSUserUnixTask(url: scriptUrl)
        task.execute(withArguments: [ "hello" ])
        debugPrint("OK")
    } catch let error {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
} else {
    debugPrint("Script not found")
}

// output: "OK"
```

This gives no error messages and "OK" is correctly displayed. But the `myscript` script seems to be completely ignored. When I run `myscript` from `Terminal` instead, it runs as intended.

The test `myscript` file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/osascript -e "tell app \"System Events\" to display dialog \"Message: $1\""
```

(The is only a test script; the real one calls `emacsclient`.) The shell script file is set executable (permission 755). Not only this shell script but also any other shell script seems ignored. For example, if the second line is replaced with `/usr/bin/printf "\a"`, it does not beep. I tried many other shell scripts but nothing seems to work.

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

I was hasty. The class document says "If the application is sandboxed, then the script must be in the `applicationScriptsDirectory` folder." Now I want to know how to copy the script file upon installation.

EDIT 2:

I manually copied `myscript` to `~/Library/Applications Scripts/com.mydomain.myApp/` and then changed the first line of the above Swift codes (`if let scriptUrl ...`) to

```
let scriptFolderUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationScriptsDirectory, 
    in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
if let scriptUrl = URL(string: "myscript", relativeTo: scriptFolderURL) {
```

https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/43741325/swift+3++sandbox++how+to+create+applicationscriptsdirectory+if+it+doesn39t+exist

The script runs. Now I need to figure out how to copy the script to the scripts folder when installing or running the app the first time.

Comment: You can't: [*A sandboxed application may read from, but not write to, this folder.* (applicationScriptsDirectory)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserunixtask). By the way, why do you run an AppleScript with `osascript` and `NSUserUnixTask` rather than directly using `NSUserAppleScriptTask`?

Comment: Thanks. I run it using `NSUserUnixTask` because there are arguments in my script, and it's not an Apple Script in my real app. What I really want is to run `emacsclient`. BTW, if writing to `applicationScriptsDirectory` is prohibited, then what is the point of having the folder? Are the users supposed to copy files manually to the script folder?

Comment: It is said in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html : "the user must manually place scripts here"

Comment: Please add your edited-into-the-question answer as a true Answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pkamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265393/pkamb) requested a proper answer. :)

As the [class document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserunixtask) says, the script must be in the `applicationScriptsDirectory` folder. This folder is not writable by a sandboxed application, as [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) pointed out. The script (`myscript`) must be copied manually to the `applicationScriptDirectory` folder (e.g., `~/Library/Applications Scripts/com.mydomain.myApp/`).

After this done, change the first line to the following:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
let scriptFolderUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationScriptsDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
if let scriptUrl = URL(string: "myscript", relativeTo: scriptFolderURL) {
// --------------------------------------------------------
    // same below
    do {
        let task = try NSUserUnixTask(url: scriptUrl)
        task.execute(withArguments: [ "hello" ])
        debugPrint("OK")
    } catch let error {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
} else {
    debugPrint("Script not found")
}
```

I benefited from [this link](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/43741325/swift+3++sandbox++how+to+create+applicationscriptsdirectory+if+it+doesn39t+exist) for the first line.